# Exclude User from Activity Stream in BuddyPress?

Tags: buddypress

I'd like to exclude a specific user account from showing up in the activity stream. 
I found this code that's supposed to exclude the Admin. Any clue how to exclude a specific user? (this code goes in bp-custom.php)

```
<?php 
add_action("plugins_loaded","bpdev_init_sm_mode");
function bpdev_init_sm_mode(){
if(is_site_admin())
remove_action("wp_head","bp_core_record_activity");//id SM is on, remove the record activity hook
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
add_action("plugins_loaded","bpdev_init_sm_mode");
function bpdev_init_sm_mode(){
    global $current_user;
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        get_currentuserinfo();
        if("someusername" == $current_user->user_login) {
            remove_action("wp_head","bp_core_record_activity");//id SM is on, remove the record activity hook
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks real good, but I put the code into bp-custom.php and activity is still recorded for that user. Thanks for the answer. If it helps, here is a link to where I originally got the code from: [link](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/stealth-mode-for-buddypress-site-admin-plugin/)

Comment: I just tested the original code, and that doesn't work either! SO i guess maybe it's for an older version of Buddypress.